# Product filtering based on custom data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a product filter based on checkbox click. It should show and hide based on `data-ftype` and will match it with the `id` of the checkbox.

I saw this on StackOverflow but my version doesn't work, and I do not know why. I would be thankful for any help.

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
  if ($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0) {
    $('.c1 >a1').hide();
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
      $('.c1 >a1[data-ftype=' + this.id + ']').show();
    });
  } else {
    $('.c1 >a1').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="full" value="fullrim" />full<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="half" value="halfrim" />half<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="without" value="without" />without<br/>
<div class="c1">
  <div class="a1" data-ftype="full">
    abc
  </div>
  <div class="a1" data-ftype="half">
    pqr
  </div>
  <div class="a1" data-ftype="without">
    stuv
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You simply forgot the dot in your `a1`class selector. Change all instances from `.c1 >a1` to `.c1 > .a1` and it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the below code, it is working now

A fix has been given to selector  instead of $('.c1 >a1') replaced with $('.c1 > .a1')

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
  if ($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0) {
    $('.c1 > .a1').hide();
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
      $('.c1 > .a1[data-ftype=' + this.id + ']').show();
    });
  } else {
    $('.c1 > .a1').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="full" value="fullrim" />full<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="half" value="halfrim" />half<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="without" value="without" />without<br/>
<div class="c1">
  <div class="a1" data-ftype="full">
    abc
  </div>
  <div class="a1" data-ftype="half">
    pqr
  </div>
  <div class="a1" data-ftype="without">
    stuv
  </div>
</div>
```